# Does Gunicorn run on Windows

Tags: python, gunicorn

I have looked around for a while, and I was surprised not finding any information whether Gunicorn runs on Windows or not.
Does anyone know if that is the case, and if so, where can I find some documentation about it?

Comment: I'm looking for the closest alternative to Gunicorn for Windows. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm using [waitress](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/waitress/en/latest/) now, very good alternative :)

Answer (score 187, accepted):

Technically this is not an answer. But **practically** the answer I was looking for is how to run a WSGI web app (like Django) on Windows, and for those who got into this page because of that, here it is:

I'm using [waitress](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/waitress/en/latest/) now, very good alternative :)

Basically all you have to do is replace the `gunicorn` call with:

```
waitress-serve --listen=*:8000 myapp.wsgi:application
```

For typical apps this will give you the same result as running gunicorn. :) Good luck!

Comment: Perfectly working for me without having to change any other code, thanks!
Though I ended up using `waitress.serve(app, listen='0.0.0.0:5003')` where `5003` is my custom port and `app` is `app = Flask(__name__)`

Comment: anyone trying to deploy to heroku, try `web: waitress-serve --port=$PORT myapp.wsgi:application`(inside Procfile), before pushing to heroku master. Use Hendy's answer ,i.e specify a port, if you are trying on heroku local

Answer (score 93):

Gunicorn is for a UNIX environment and is incompatible with Windows.
Also for more info please refer to it's [docs](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/index.html).

Comment: See my answer below, cygwin support is not far away

Comment: Gunicorn states that clearly, but all of the Uvicorn documentation does not mention the Linux requirement on github, pypi, or uvicorn.com.

Answer (score 27):

Edit: there's now a plan to add Windows support. https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/524

---

No. Gunicorn doesn't run on Windows. It's very design is to take 'advantage of features in Unix/Unix-like kernels'.

Answer (score 10):

gunicorn used not to run directly on Windows, but work (and pending issues being resolved) mean that you can make it work on Cygwin.

See https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/407 ....

(Note: I update this answer because the bug has now been fixed)

Comment: Using the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) on Windows 10 is a valid alternative to Cygwin (if not better) nowadays.

Answer (score 6):

Gunicorn does not support windows, although you can use [waitress](https://www.docketrun.com/blog/waitress-alternative-flask-gunicorn/)

Answer (score 5):

I'm trying to Build ASGI app on windows using FASTAPI. FASTAPI is run on Gunicorn & Uvicorn server.I read the FASTAPI [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/deployment/) to find out how to deploy my app on windows. They suggesting to use docker to deploy the app from windows. It turns out to be the best way to use Gunicorn on windows.

Answer (score 4):

On Windows, you can install guvicorn like that:

```
pip install uvicorn gunicorn
```

And then, run your server using the notation available in https://www.uvicorn.org/. Example:

```
uvicorn myproject.asgi:application --host 127.0.0.1 --port 80 --reload
```

It's how I use in production and it's being consistent to serve my Django ASGI applications.

Comment: How to run uvicorn in daemon mode on windows?