# Foreman exiting immediately with code 1

Tags: python, django, heroku, foreman

I am having trouble with getting foreman to work.

When I run `foreman start`, I get the following output:

```
13:48:12 web.1  | started with pid 14896
13:48:12 web.1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
13:48:12 web.1  |   File "C:\Python33\Scripts\gunicorn-script.py", line 9, in <module>
13:48:12 web.1  |     load_entry_point('gunicorn==18.0', 'console_scripts', 'gunicorn')()
13:48:12 web.1  |   File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 357, in load_entry_point
13:48:12 web.1  |     return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
13:48:12 web.1  |   File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 2394, in load_entry_point
13:48:12 web.1  |     return ep.load()
13:48:12 web.1  |   File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 2108, in load
13:48:12 web.1  | exited with code 1
13:48:12 web.1  |     entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
13:48:12 system | sending SIGKILL to all processes
13:48:12        |   File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\gunicorn\app\wsgiapp.py", line 10, in <module>
```

Frankly, I don't have a clue what is causing this. Help would be much appreciated.

My Procfile is as follows:

```
web: gunicorn caraton.wsgi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit late here so I expect you've worked this out for yourself, but as you appear to be in a Windows environment, gunicorn does not currently run on Windows. This is referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11087682/does-gunicorn-run-on-windows) on stackoverflow.

Windows support is apparently planned as described [here](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/524).

I ran into the same problem myself.

Comment: I did figure it out by now, but thanks for your answer.