# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fcntl'

Tags: python, flask, server, gunicorn

for flask application run using gunicorn

```
$ pip install gunicorn
$ gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 app:app
```

**getting error**

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\shubham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
> "**main**", mod_spec)
> File "C:\Users\shubham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in *run_code
> exec(code, run_globals)
> File "C:\Users\shubham\Desktop\Full_stack_developer\venv\Scripts\gunicorn.exe_*main**.py", line 5, in 
> File "c:\users\shubham\desktop\full_stack_developer\venv\lib\site-packages\gunicorn\app\wsgiapp.py", line 9, in 
> from gunicorn.app.base import Application
> File "c:\users\shubham\desktop\full_stack_developer\venv\lib\site-packages\gunicorn\app\base.py", line 11, in 
> from gunicorn import util
> File "c:\users\shubham\desktop\full_stack_developer\venv\lib\site-packages\gunicorn\util.py", line 9, in 
> import fcntl
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fcntl'

Answer (score 34):

The module fctnl is not available on Windows systems

Comment: How to use gunicorn in window machine for flask app or i can't

Comment: Unfortunately Gunicorn is for a UNIX environment and is incompatible with Windows. https://stackoverflow.com/a/11087777/12362709

Answer (score 29):

It has already been mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/11087777/12362709 (thanks to @Necklondon) but copying it here since it's useful:

```
pip install waitress
waitress-serve --listen=*:8000 app:app
```

Comment: It's waitress-serve

Comment: Thank you, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to run gunicorn on windows, this is possible using the Ubuntu terminal available for windows: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/ubuntu-on-windows#1-overview

The terminal will allow linux commands to work. I use it to run gunicorn myself.