# How can we deploy a Machine Learning Model using Flask?

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda, conda

I am trying, for the first time ever, to deploy a ML model, using Flask. I'm following the instructions from the link below.

https://towardsdatascience.com/deploy-a-machine-learning-model-using-flask-da580f84e60c

I created three separate and distinct .py files named 'model.py', 'server.py', and 'request.py'. I open my Anaconda Prompt end entered this: 'C:\Users\ryans>C:\Users\ryans\model.py'

Now, I get this.

[image]

I definitely have Numpy installed! Something must be wrong with my setup, or maybe the way I am starting the process is wrong, but I'm not sure what the issue is. Has anyone encountered this problem before.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following steps since you mentioned its your first time and when deploying a project for experimenting, it's good practice to put it in a virtual environment, which we can do with the [`virtualenv`](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) tool.

1. Assuming you already have `pip` installed, install virtualenv:

   `C:\> pip install virtualenv`
2. Create a fresh working directory, switch to it and [clone the repository from Github](https://github.com/vyashemang/flask-salary-predictor) mentioned by the author of the article:

   `C:\your-working-directory\> git clone https://github.com/vyashemang/flask-salary-predictor.git`
3. Start virtualenv in the repository's top directory

   `C:\your-working-directory\flask-salary-predictor\> virtualenv env`
4. Activate the created batch file, `\env\Scripts\activate.bat`:

   `C:\Users\'Username'\venv\Scripts\activate.bat`
5. Now in the virtual environment, install all requirements:

   `(env) C:\your-working-directory\flask-salary-predictor\> pip install -r requirements.txt`
6. You can now run the `model.py` like you have above. I'd suggest that you run the server.py using gunicorn or [on Windows use waitress according to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11087682/does-gunicorn-run-on-windows) so that instead of running `request.py` every time you want to send a request, you can use [Insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/) or [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) to send API requests.

Comment: Is there and easier way to do this? Seems like there should be. If not, it's fine. I need to do a deep dive into this tomorrow. Thanks for sharing your insights!!

Comment: When in doubt, follow the installation documentation for [`numpy`](https://numpy.org/install/) again and the instructions given in the Medium article.